# Understanding code in c (linked lists)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am having big problems understanding linked lists and I would be very thankful if someone could explain me the following.

```
Element_t *pushfront(Element_t *list)
{ 
if(list==0)
return allocate();

list->prev=allocate();

list->prev->next=list;

list=list->prev;

return list;
}
```

What here means `list->prev->next=list` ?

What means this: `f->next->prev=f->prev`?

I know that this is just a part from program code, but I hope someone can give me general meaning of these as simpliest as can?

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html     Good explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list has nodes that have references to the previous node and to the next node in the list.

The function gets the first node of the list. So this first node does not have a previous node.

In this statement

```
list->prev=allocate();
```

a previous node is created because as it follows from the function name it push a new node at the beginning of the list.

In this statement

```
list->prev->next=list;
```

expression `list->prev` yields the address of the new created node. This created node shall point to the current first node of the list. Thus its data member `next` shall contain the address of the node `list`.

And this statement

```
list->prev->next=list;
```

does this.

It can be imagined simpler if to introduce an intermediate variable.

For example

```
Element_t *new_node = allocate();

list->prev = new_node;      // list->prev=allocate();
new_node->next = list;     //list->prev->next=list;
list = new_node;           //list=list->prev;

return list;
```

As for this question

> What means this: f->next->prev=f->prev?

then it looks like that the node `f` is removed from the list. Now its next node (`f->next`) will not point to `f` but will point to the preceding node of `f`.

Again it will be more clear if to introduce intermediate variables.

```
Element_t *previous_node_of_f = f->prev;
Element_t *next_node_of_f = f->next;

next_node_of_f->prev = previous_node_of_f;  // f->next->prev=f->prev
```

If to add also a statement like this

```
previous_node_of_f->next = next_node_of_f;
```

then the node `f` will be fully removed from the list.

```
       --------------------------------------------------------
       |                                              prev    ^
       |                                                      |
----------------------    ----------------------    ----------------------
| previous_node_of_f |    |         f          |    |    next_node_of_f  |    
----------------------    ----------------------    ----------------------
       |                                                     ^  
       |    next                                             | 
       -------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with comments, which tell you what is happening.

```
Element_t *pushfront(Element_t *list)
{ 
if(list==0) // If the list is emtpy
return allocate(); /* then you simply create a new node, which 
represents your list and return it. The size of your list grew from 0 to 1.*/

list->prev=allocate(); /*If the list is not empty, you add a new node by creating it,
and then the prev pointer of the first element in the list (list->prev) 
is set to this new element, as you want it to be first.*/

list->prev->next=list; /*Then you need to set the next pointer 
to the element you just added. The new element is at list->prev, 
so by list->prev->next, you just say, that the next element of the one
 you just created is the element that was first before you added the new one*/

list=list->prev; /* Here you just set the new element as the head of the list*/

return list; /*And here you return the new list*/
}
```

Note, that your list is always passed just as a pointer to the first element, as that's all you need. You can then access all of the elements by `next` pointer, which is set for each element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the linked lists are linked each others with pointers. They are not in order in fact they are distributed on memory.

Let me get on your question-1 `list->prev->next=list`;
Here you are linking the previous node with the current node. This code means that link the next of previous to the current node. Then the previous node now linked with next pointer which is defined in structure.
Get the question-2  `f->next->prev=f->prev`;
I dont know where this is defined but here you are doing that a circled linked list. The last node linked to the first node by this code.

Answer (score 0):

`Element_t` is a probably a `typedef` similar to the following:

```
typedef struct Element {
    struct Element * next;
    struct Element * prev;
    void * data;
} Element_t;
```

Assuming this, your linked list basicly works like this:

```
                  (list)
                     A               B               C
                +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
                | next=B   |--->| next=C   |--->| next=0   |
                | prev=0   |<---| prev=A   |<---| prev=B   |
                | data="A" |    | data="B" |    | data="C" |
                +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
```

So now you want to add a new node N in front of A

```
                  (list)
     N               A               B               C
+----------+    +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
| next=A   |--->| next=B   |--->| next=C   |--->| next=0   |
| prev=0   |<---| prev=N   |<---| prev=A   |<---| prev=B   |
| data="N" |    | data="A" |    | data="B" |    | data="C" |
+----------+    +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
```

so, 1. A->prev needs to be set to N and 2. N->next needs to set to A.

`list->prev=allocate();` this allocates the new N and already assigns A->prev=N.

Next in line: `list->prev->next=list`: Read `list->prev` as the new node that just got alloced. Then it's N->next=A - the second step.

And your new element is linked in the list. Obviously, `allocate()` needs to initialize `next` and `prev` to `NULL`.

> What means this: f->next->prev=f->prev?

Depends on where it's written. Here, it's probably part of a function, that removes a node from the list.